# Prevent craftcms caching CMS page with dynamic template

Tags: cache

I understood CraftCMS caching should exclude dynamic values, however I have a page built as an Entity within CraftCMS admin which `{% include %}`'s a template with a form.  The templates dynamic form values are somehow being rendered with cached values.

The included template form uses dynamic values from e.g. `{{ craft.session.getFlash(key, '') }}` which are getting cached by CraftCMS causing the form to render with someone else's session values.

Neither the Entity nor template had `{% cache %}` flags, and I've tried various cache settings to try and prevent such as `{% cache unless craft.session.hasFlash('key') %}` within the form template, and before the `{% include %}` within the Entity page, however the template is still rendered with cached form values.

This is CraftCMS 2.4 with no custom caching plugins, using a Redis cache store and default Craft caching config values.

How can I prevent this? Thanks!

Comment: Are there `{% cache %}` tags anywhere in your code? E.g. in a base template or anything else wrapping the entry or form templates?

Comment: I feel silly, that was it!  A higher level template this was extending had a cache tag.  Thanks @MatsMikkelRummelhoff!

Comment: No worries, @JamesMartin. I'll add an answer too, for good measure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`{% cache %}`](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/cache) tag does *not* exclude dynamic data.

What it does, is to basically make note of any [element criteria](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/elementcriteriamodel) (i.e. any code relating to pulling entries, categories, assets, tags or users) contained in the Twig code inside the `{% cache %}{% endcache %}` pair.

Then, whenever something triggers a change to the related element criteria (e.g. if an entry is edited, published or deleted), the cache will automatically be cleared.

This is all related to elements, though – so any other dynamic data you may have in your template, such as session variables, will not trigger the same behaviour.

If your entry or form templates doesn't have any `{% cache %}` tags, I'm guessing you do have some in a base template wrapping your entry and form templates? If so, you'll need to take a more granular approach to your caching, e.g. by caching components separately and avoid `{% cache %}` tag nesting. To that end, your `unless` statement should work nicely for escaping dynamic data caching, as long as the component you're caching isn't wrapped by a higher-level `{% cache %}` tag.